# error al hacer llamada GET en angular

Tags: angular, flask

Estoy intentando hacer una aplicacion super sencilla **flask - angular**.

Desde **flask** devuelvo un *"ok"* sin mas, y estoy intentando configurar el servicio. Tengo esto:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { Respuesta } from './respuesta';


@Injectable()
export class ServicioPruebaService 
{
  prueba:String;

  constructor(private _http: Http) 
  { 

  }

  llamada():Observable<String>
  {
    return this._http.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/hola");
  }

}
```

Pero me da error, si le pongo:

```
return this._http.get<String>("http://127.0.0.1:5000/hola");
```

Tampoco funciona, y me dice:

> "Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1"

¿Podéis ayudarme a configurar un servicio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El motivo del error es porque debes usar el cliente HTTP de angular y no la function Http a pelo.

Cambia lo siguiente:

```js
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
/* */
constructor(private _http: HttpClient)
```

Asegurate que en tu `app.module.ts` tienes incluido el modulo de Http tambien: **HttpClientModule** (`import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http'`)